# Using the grep and cut delimiter command (in bash shell scripting UNIX) - and kind of "reversing" it?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, grep, cut

So I have a file with the text:

```
puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

I want to use the grep command

```
grep puddle2_1557936
```

Mixed in with the cut command (or another command if neccessary) to display just this part:

```
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

So far, I know that if do this

```
 grep puddle2_1557936 | cut -d ":" -f1
```

then it will display

```
puddle2_1557936
```

So is there anyway to kind of "inverse" the delimiter cut command?

NOTE: The solution *must* start off with `grep puddle2_15579636`.

Comment: minimal fix is to use `-f2` with `cut`. Btw why must it start with `grep puddle2_15579636`, will something bad happen if it doesn't?

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know the fix was that easy...haha.

Also it had to start with grep puddle2_15579636 because I'm writing quite a long script, and at that point in the script, the only information available would be that! 

Its kind of hard to explain unless you see the whole project!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You don't need to change the delimiter to display the right part of the string with `cut`.

The `-f` switch of the `cut` command is the n-TH element separated by your delimiter : `:`, so you can just type :

```
 grep puddle2_1557936 | cut -d ":" -f2
```

---

Another solutions (adapt it a bit) if you want fun :

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
grep -oP 'puddle2_1557936:\K.*' <<< 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'                                                                        
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or still with [look around](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

```
grep -oP '(?<=puddle2_1557936:).*' <<< 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'                                                                    
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne '/puddle2_1557936:(.*)/ and print $1' <<< 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'                                                      
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or using [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) (thanks to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman))

```
ruby -F: -ane '/puddle2_1557936/ and puts $F[1]' <<< 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F'puddle2_1557936:' '{print $2}'  <<< 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or with [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1].split("puddle2_1557936:")[1])' 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or using only [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
IFS=: read _ a <<< "puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2"
echo "$a"
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or using [js](/questions/tagged/js) in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
js<<EOF
var x = 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2'
print(x.substr(x.indexOf(":")+1))
EOF
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

or using [php](/questions/tagged/php) in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
php -r 'preg_match("/puddle2_1557936:(.*)/", $argv[1], $m); echo "$m[1]\n";' 'puddle2_1557936:/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2' 
/home/rogers.williams/folderz/puddle2
```

Comment: Where is `python` and `ruby`?? +1

Comment: :p Thanks! Only needed it for bash but extra info doesn't hurt haha

Comment: With `awk` do we really need that big `-F`?

Comment: No : `awk -F':' '{print $2}'`

Comment: Correct, your answer says something different. :)

Comment: `awk -F '/puddle2_1557936/ {print $2}'` actually

Comment: btw, the ruby is very similar to perl: `ruby -F: -ane '/puddle2_1557936/ and puts $F[1]' `

Comment: although cryptic, you can use `__import__('module')` when using python;
so another approach could be: `__import__('sys').argv[0]`